# VBA copy WebTable to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro, that opens IE and navigates to a webpage. So now on the webpage, there are multiple tables. I'm trying to copy the last one to the page in Excel for further calculations but it copies all the values from the whole table in a single cell.How do I get the code to split the text into cells? The columns will be fixed for each page, but the number of rows might vary.

```
Worksheets("temp").Range("A1").Value = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("Table")(32).innertext
```

Comment: Please add to the question the webpage URL.

Comment: Look into QueryTables  as well. And what do you expect if you use Range("A1") =  ???  It is one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have used in the past:

Because the table will more likely have rows and columns (td,tr) you can not assign the whole data to a single Range/Cell.

The method I ended using was to copy the whole table to the clipboard and Paste it on Cell/Range A1.

```
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.SetText ie.document.getelementsbytagname("Table")(32).outerHTML
clipboard.PutInClipboard
Worksheets("temp").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

Edit: You will need to add the Reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library